# PHP: Adding a number of images in one line

Tags: php, image

i used this code to get all images in one folder to my page but don't know how to specify the number of images in each row for example i want only 6 images in a line
 please help

```
<p align="center">
<?php
$dirname = "images2/boys/fig/";
$images = glob($dirname."*");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="a" onclick="window.open(this.src);"/>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want, here's one:
Use `css` and set `display:inline-block` on the desired div , i.e.:

```css
  div.myClass{
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="myClass">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
```

---

Using `PHP`:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
echo <<< EOF
<div class="container">
<img src="$image" onclick="window.open(this.src);" class="myClass" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
EOF;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome zaidf . If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer and give it 1up, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css styling. First insert the images in a parent div with a fixed width and style the images to display according to your desire:

```
<div class="img_wrap">
<?php
$dirname = "images2/boys/fig/";
$images = glob($dirname."*");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="a" onclick="window.open(this.src);"/>';
}

?>
</div>
```

css styling:

```
.img_wrap {
    width:600px; /*this can be any value*/
    height:auto;
}

.a {
    width:85px; /*this can be any value*/
    height:85px; /*for getting a squared image. *this can be any value*/
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
```